# Vaadin 24.2.5: TextFields do not get focus by mouse click

Tags: vaadin

There is a strange behaviour of TextFields (and TextAreas) in my applications when built with Vaadin 24.2.5. Most of TextFields and TextAreas (but not all) do *not* get the focus when clicked into, but they can be accessed with TAB key. A field.focus() in Java code does work as well (but of course only for the first time). Other components, including ComboBoxes, seem to work as expected.

Things were still fine with Vaadin 24.2.4, double-checked this.

Has anyone an idea what goes wrong here?

Thanks,
Torsten